# How to retrieve a Pokemon Go Account

Tags: pokemon-go

I had a Pokemon Go Account that was level 15 and when I attempted to change the password on my account I couldn't login anymore. Could I have some help please?

Comment: We need some more context with these kinds of things...did you do anything other than change your password?

Comment: Check your emails for another confirmation mail or reset your password again.

Answer (score 2):

If You used a password, you most likely signed up in Trainer Club". Google+ doesn't require a password.

Follow this link: https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-password

Make sure you select "request desktop site" in your tools menu in your browser. If you don't, you will not be able to reset password from mobile phone.

Enter your email address you signed up with and a email will be sent to you. At the bottom of that email, click on the link "Reset Your Password".

Comment: Thanks LionWaffles for the help. Wrote this about half asleep lol.

Answer (score 0):

I retrieved mine I had logged in on an old gmail account....if you uninstaLL and sign up under the original one it should work.  It took me 2 days and I had to change my password on the correct account because I had forgotten it but it worked.  Tonight I am back on level 33 just as when I lost it.  Hope this helps